# Track Changes in Oracle SQL with data

Tags: sql, oracle

I was looking to find out how i can track value changes in a table that I have as I currently want to be able capture the first date for the attribute but this falls over if I have a scenario where attribute A becomes attribute B a couple of days later and then goes back to attribute A again in a weeks time.

The following is my dataset:

```
Attributes | DateTime
A | 01/08/2017 00:01:45
A | 02/08/2017 00:30:00
B | 03/08/2017 00:45:57
A | 07/08/2017 13:00:00
```

Now I can write the following:

```
SELECT Attributes, MIN(DateTime);
```

which gives me:

```
Attributes | DateTime
A | 01/08/2017 00:01:45
B | 03/08/2017 00:45:57
```

but what I would like is to be able to see Attribute A again but not sure how i go about doing it.

```
Attributes | DateTime
A | 01/08/2017 00:01:45
B | 03/08/2017 00:45:57
A | 07/08/2017 13:00:00
```

Would appreciate if somebody could advise on how i go about doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LAG()` to compare to the last record :

```
SELECT p.*
FROM(
    SELECT t.* 
           LAG(t.attributes) OVER(ORDER BY t.DateTime) as Last_Atrribute
    FROM YourTable t) p
WHERE p.attributes <> p.last_attribute
```

If you always want the first record, change your `WHERE` to this:

```
WHERE p.attributes <> COALESCE(p.last_attribute,'-1')
```

Or in other words:

```
WHERE p.last_attribute IS NULL OR p.attributes <> p.last_attribute
```

Of course you can change the query to select only expected columns . I used `*` asterisk for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `LAG` analytic function:

```
SELECT attributes,
       datetime
FROM   (
  SELECT attributes,
         datetime,
         LAG( Attributes ) OVER ( ORDER BY DateTime ) AS prev_attributes
  FROM   your_table
)
WHERE  prev_attributes IS NULL
OR     attributes <> prev_attributes
```

Comment: Because you got the comment in 20 seconds after I posted before I got the edit in tidying up the answer 30 seconds later.... and because the SQL parser should be clever enough to optimise in the case of repeated use of the same function call in one statement.

Comment: Thanks will give that a go and let you know how i get on

Comment: Just commented in case you didn't notice. I know you know it. Although the SQL parser "should" be clever , repeated code is more confusing and may lead to more errors, and the cleverness is not guaranteed..